# How do I pip a package from Azure DevOps in a conda environment file?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pip, conda

**Goal:**

I would like to add a custom package from Azure DevOps to my conda environment file from the "dev" branch.

**Result from SSH:**

try ssh version -> git+ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/c19analytics/c19_lib/c19_lib.git@dev

error ->

Installing pip dependencies: / Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['/home/frosty/anaconda3/envs/c19_rtc/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', '/home/frosty/code/c19_refresh_token_controller/condaenv.w2bop1rz.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:
Collecting git+ssh://****@ssh.dev.azure.com/c19analytics/c19_lib/c19_lib.git@dev (from -r /home/frosty/code/c19_refresh_token_controller/condaenv.w2bop1rz.requirements.txt (line 1))
Cloning ssh://****@ssh.dev.azure.com/c19analytics/c19_lib/c19_lib.git (to revision dev) to /tmp/pip-req-build-3skuxttv

Pip subprocess error:
Running command git clone -q 'ssh://****@ssh.dev.azure.com/c19analytics/c19_lib/c19_lib.git' /tmp/pip-req-build-3skuxttv
remote: Command git-upload-pack '/c19analytics/c19_lib/c19_lib.git' is not in expected format.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
WARNING: Discarding git+ssh://****@ssh.dev.azure.com/c19analytics/c19_lib/c19_lib.git@dev. Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q 'ssh://****@ssh.dev.azure.com/c19analytics/c19_lib/c19_lib.git' /tmp/pip-req-build-3skuxttv Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q 'ssh://****@ssh.dev.azure.com/c19analytics/c19_lib/c19_lib.git' /tmp/pip-req-build-3skuxttv Check the logs for full command output.
failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed

**Result from HTTPS**

try https version -> git+https://c19analytics@dev.azure.com/c19analytics/c19_lib/_git/c19_lib@dev

error ->

Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['/home/frosty/anaconda3/envs/c19_rtc/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', '/home/frosty/code/c19_refresh_token_controller/condaenv.fvnohwu8.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:
Collecting git+https://****@dev.azure.com/c19analytics/c19_lib/_git/c19_lib (from -r /home/frosty/code/c19_refresh_token_controller/condaenv.fvnohwu8.requirements.txt (line 1))
Cloning https://****@dev.azure.com/c19analytics/c19_lib/_git/c19_lib to /tmp/pip-req-build-q2i5sjad

Pip subprocess error:
Running command git clone -q 'https://****@dev.azure.com/c19analytics/c19_lib/_git/c19_lib' /tmp/pip-req-build-q2i5sjad
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://c19analytics@dev.azure.com/c19analytics/c19_lib/_git/c19_lib/'
WARNING: Discarding git+https://****@dev.azure.com/c19analytics/c19_lib/_git/c19_lib. Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q 'https://****@dev.azure.com/c19analytics/c19_lib/_git/c19_lib' /tmp/pip-req-build-q2i5sjad Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q 'https://****@dev.azure.com/c19analytics/c19_lib/_git/c19_lib' /tmp/pip-req-build-q2i5sjad Check the logs for full command output.
failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed

**Conda Environment File**

```
name: c19_rtc
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python
  - requests
  - pip
  - pip:
    - git+ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/c19analytics/c19_lib/c19_lib.git@dev
    #- git+https://c19analytics@dev.azure.com/c19analytics/c19_lib/_git/c19_lib
```